# How to get / post method in rspec rails6

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rspec3

m new to rails

I am using RSpec gem for testing

**This is my controller**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_user, except: %i[show index]

  before_action :authorize_user, only: %i[edit update destroy]
  def index
    @questions = Question.all

  end

  def show
    @answers = Answer.where('question_id = :question_id ', { question_id: params[:id] })
    @count = Answer.where('question_id = :question_id ', { question_id: params[:id] }).count
    $count_global = @count
    session[:question_id] = params[:id]
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end


  def edit; end
  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.user_id *strong text*= current_user.id
    @question.save

    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

**This is spec/requests/question_spec.rb**

```
  describe "GET /new" do
    it "renders a successful response" do
      get new_question_url
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
```

The test is not passing
**The error is**

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_successful
       expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x0000558594f082e0 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x0000558594f08290>, @mon_data_..., @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil>>.successful?` to be truthy, got false
```

**Could anyone help regarding this issue**

Comment: Quick tip; `Answer.where('question_id = :question_id ', { question_id: params[:id] })` might be rewritten as `Answer.where(question_id: params[:id])`

Comment: What's the RSpec version you're using and are you adding the `type: :request` to the spec?

Comment: I am using rspec 4.0.1

Comment: you are sending get request but you want to access post method ? e.g new

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails Rspec test case for edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65562959/rails-rspec-test-case-for-edit)