# Rails Rspec test case for edit

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rspec3

Hello I'm new to rails

I am writing test cases for using rspec gem

In my controller I have edit function. I have before action for edit function
**This is my controller**

```
before_action :authorize_user, only: %i[edit update destroy]
def edit
end

**private**

  def authorize_user
    id = Question.find(params[:id]).user_id
    redirect_to root_path if id != current_user.id
  end
```

**This is my rspec/requests/question_rspec.rb**

```
  describe "GET /edit" do
    before do
      sign_in(create(:user)) # Factory Bot user
    end
    it "render a successful response" do
      question = create(:question) #Factory bot question
      # question.user = current_user
      question.save
      get edit_question_url(question)
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end

  end
```

**I'm getting an error like**

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_successful
       expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x00005652448f4c50 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00005652448f4c00>, @mon_data_..., @method=nil, @request_method=nil, @remote_ip=nil, @original_fullpath=nil, @fullpath=nil, @ip=nil>>.successful?` to be truthy, got false
     # ./spec/requests/questions_spec.rb:105:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

**Could anyone please let me know**

Comment: just comment out before_action and check again, I think before action causes this

Comment: I removed the before action. Now it was successful. But the test with the authorize_user function is necessary.

Comment: just put debugger their and find why the user is not authorizing from their, or I'm not familiar with the santax you are using can you please elaborate this Question.find(params[:id]).user_id   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is something related to your commented code.

Probably, this statement `id != current_user.id` is true. So, to fix it, you need to set the created user to the question to avoid being redirected in your `authorize_user` callback.

here some test case changes:

```
  describe "GET /edit" do
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }

    before do
      sign_in(user) # Factory Bot user
    end

    it "render a successful response" do
      question = create(:question, user: user) #Factory bot question
      # question.save # you don't need it because the create operation already saves it
      get edit_question_url(question)
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
```